# Find maximal elements of list (remove dominated elements)

Tags: list-manipulation, maximum

Suppose I consider `a` to be greater than `b` if `a[[1]] >= b[[1]]` and `a[[2]] >= b[[2]]` and at least one is greater. Given a list of elements, how do I best pick out the maximal elements?

Comment: Perhaps `FindPeak` ? Show your list nad you might get helpful answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) ["ParetoListMinima"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ParetoListMinima) to do this. For example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomInteger[20, {10, 2}]
```

> {{5, 0}, {7, 0}, {2, 3}, {0, 0}, {16, 14}, {3, 8}, {19, 5}, {18, 16}, {12,
> 0}, {19, 4}}

Then:

```
-ResourceFunction["ParetoListMinima"][-data]
```

> {{18, 16}, {19, 5}}